# I am fetching the collection from server once the save is complete. But as fetch is async the view is rendering before fetch is complete

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am calling a fetch on a collection and inside its success methods fetching another collection. Once its done I am adding both the collections and rendering to the view. After I save a new item in the view, it saves in the db and after save is complete I am calling the methods that does fetching. All I want to do is to render the updated collection which now should include a newly crated model. But, When I debug step by step using chrome debugger, it gets the updated collection from the server otherwise the collection is not getting updated. I assume it is rendering before fetching. Page refresh is working just fine. Can you suggest anything I can do to change or delay rendering until fetch is complete?

Comment: You said it!Try to Create the view when fetch is complete.

Comment: I am doing that, but it doesnt render updated collection fro some reason. A refresh after it is doing it perfectly.

Comment: I guess the best way to debug this is to step through Backbone.js source code and see what happens when you create the view

Comment: I just looked at it again and I think the problem is not with fetch but with the save or destroy I am using a method save that will perform the Update and DElete operations on the models. Right after Update or delete is done am calling the method that does fetching for db. I assume by the time it fetches for db the save or destroy is not complete. Can we make those calls (destroy and save) not async?

Comment: Those calls are naturally async because they need speak to the server.

Comment: well is there a way to wait until those calls are complete before I render(fetch updated collection) the view again?

Comment: Can you update your question with some code snippets?  Hard to help you if I can't look at the code as well.

Comment: It is in bits and pieces in different functions I dunno if I can add it here. One thing I just noticed is after calling model.destroy(); I am calling this.displayAllRows(); displayAllRows method is responsible for fetching from the server. 
So in the page it doenst get updated. I put and alert box just before calling this.displayAllRows();and it works perfect. I dont understand what that means. Does it mean I must wait a little before I render my view ?

Comment: You can use a jQuery promise with model.destroy and when it is done call displayAllRows.

Comment: can you give me an example for it. I looked it up but if you can tell me how exactly I must use it in my case, that would be great.

Comment: By the way I am calling destroy method inside a loop of models that need to be deleted.So where exactly I can use promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you have given me, you should be able to do something like this.

```
var promises = [];
_.each(models, function (model) {
    var destroying = model.destroy();
    promises.push(destroying);
});

$.when.apply(null, promises).done(this.displayAllRows);
```

You will probably have to modify this but this should give you an idea of what you can do to destroy all your models and then render your rows.